# Generic sliding average in C++

Tags: c++, template, statistics

I tried hard to come up with a function template computing a sliding average. A sliding average over data \$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\$ with window length \$k \leq n\$ is a sequence \$y_1, y_2, \dots, y_{n - k + 1}\$, where
$$y_i = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} x_{i + j}.$$

Here is my attempt:

**mymath.h**

```
#ifndef MYMATH_H
#define MYMATH_H

#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator>
void sliding_average(ForwardIterator begin,
                     ForwardIterator end,
                     OutputIterator output,
                     size_t window_length)
{
    if (window_length == 0)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Bad window_length: ";
        ss << window_length;
        throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
    }

    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type;

    ForwardIterator finger = begin;
    T sum {};
    size_t count = 0;

    while (finger != end and count < window_length)
    {
        sum += *finger++;
        count++;
    }

    if (count < window_length)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "The length of the range (";
        ss << count;
        ss << ") is too short. Must be at least ";
        ss << window_length;
        throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
    }

    *output++ = sum / window_length;
    ForwardIterator window_tail = begin;

    while (finger != end)
    {
        sum -= *window_tail++;
        sum += *finger++;
        *output++ = sum / window_length;
    }
}

#endif // MYMATH_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mymath.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::begin;
using std::end;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float input[15];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        input[i] = i + 1;
    }

    float output[11];

    sliding_average(begin(input), end(input), begin(output), 5);

    for (auto& a : output)
    {
        cout << a << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Critique request**

I would like to receive comments regarding how to make my implementation more generic, and how to make it more idiomatic. Other comments are welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good. There are small things that could be improved.

It is possible to give `window_length` type `std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type`. I think `std::size_t` is fine for most cases.

```
ForwardIterator begin,
ForwardIterator end
```

Usually those are called `first` and `last`.

```
if (window_length == 0)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Bad window_length: ";
    ss << window_length;
    throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
}
```

Well, the result of `ss.str()` is obvious :) It is possible to write `constexpr` there, or throw the string right into the constructor. Also, `runtime_error` is a good fit, but it has child called `invalid_argument`, which perfectly matches the case.

```
if (count < window_length)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "The length of the range (";
    ss << count;
    ss << ") is too short. Must be at least ";
    ss << window_length;
    throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
}
```

I think that using `std::stringstream` is an overkill here. Throwing just `"The length of the range is too short. It must be at least of length window_length"` is pretty good by itself, since most IDEs will probably stop execution, so that programmers could have a look. Even if they had a catch for this, they would need to parse a string to be actually able to do something. I don't think it worth the troubles it brings.

**Some caveats:**

Currently if `T = int` the algorithm is going to produce somewhat incorrect results. May be you could write something like warning mechanism that will warn when integer type is used. I would consider `#pragma message("your warning message here")`. It might get portability problems but the code will still compile since unrecognized `#pragma`s are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

- I would define two types

  ```
  using input_type = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type;
  using output_type = typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIterator>::value_type;
  ```

  You then perform the summation with `input_type` and cast to `output_type` before division.

  ```
  input_type sum {};
  ...
  *output++ = static_cast<output_type>(sum) / window_length;
  ```

  This way you get floating-point division if you want floating-point output and integer division if you want integer output.
- Your exceptions are too verbose for my liking.  I would change them to the following:

  ```
  throw std::runtime_error{"window_length must be greater than 0"};
  ```

  and

  ```
  throw std::runtime_error{"Input size must be greater than or equal to window_length"};
  ```
- Naming

  I would change `finger` to `window_end` and `window_tail` to `window_begin`.  Also possibly change `window_length` to `window_size`.

Comment: I believe that overload resolution of `operator/` should make it work without explicit cast, if there is no 2 step casting (one explicit + one implicit) being implied.

Comment: @Incomputable Do not let the template fool you.  If `input` is an array of `int` and `output` is an array of `double` then `sum` is of type `int`.   Therefore, the expression `sum / window_length` is computed in integer arithmetic even though `output` holds `double`.  My suggestion is that if the `output` holds `double` or `float` then use floating-point division.  On the other hand, if `output` holds an integral type then use integer division irrespective of what `input` holds.

Comment: If you keep `output` as `float`, change `input` to `int`, and put in a more interesting sequence like say the Fibonacci numbers then you will see the difference between the two approaches.  My approach boils down to using as much precision as is available to you.

Comment: Thanks, didn't consider that. Though I believe there should be some way to opt in for that cast, because otherwise I think it might be hiding something dangerous.

Comment: @Incomputable I wouldn't muddy up the interface with such details.  In my opinion the user is implicitly asking for floating-precision if they pass a floating-precision type in as output.  This may not always be true, but you cannot please everyone.  The user can post-process to remove decimal precision if they want.  Regardless, I will edit the answer to address this cast in more detail.